# unity2d move a game object towards a random position

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

i have a satellite which i let spawn randomly in a different script by just using the method `Satellite()` and i want it move towards the bottom of the screen but not towards the middle but again a random position of the ground. the problem is that `satellitedirection` is always 0. also, if i somehow would manage to get the problem solved, wouldn´t every satellite on the screen move towards the same position?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SatelliteBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D satelliteRB;
    [SerializeField] Transform satelliteFirePoint;
    [SerializeField] GameObject satellitePrefab;
    float satellitedirection;

    void Start()
    {
        

    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0,0,80*Time.deltaTime);
        //satelliteRB.velocity = -transform.up * 5;
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(satellitedirection, -15), 1 * Time.deltaTime);

        Debug.Log(satellitedirection);
        
    }

    public void Satellite()
    {
        Instantiate(satellitePrefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(-18,18),10), Quaternion.identity);
        satellitedirection = Random.Range(-18, 18);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set `satellitedirection = Random.Range(-18, 18);` inside `Start()`

Comment: Mentioned in the question that the objects are spawned from a different script. You can't set it in the Start() function

Comment: It looks like SatelliteBehaviour script is supposed to be on satellitePrefab based on what we have inside Update(). It does not matter when you set random direction. If value is 0, that means it never gets its random value from Satelite() function. This can be changed if random value is chosen before Update() inside Start() to be sure that this will not happen. I would suggest to move Satellite() function inside another script that only spawns satellites and does not move them

Comment: i do not know why but now that i put it in start it actually works just fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Instantiate()` method returns a game object but it is not assigned to anything. Assign a `var` and set its position and rotation.

```
GameObject satelliteObj = Instantiate(satellitePrefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(-18,18),10), Quaternion.identity);

// random rotation
satelliteObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector2(Random.Range(-180, 180), Random.Range(-180, 180)));
```

Comment: cool thank you will try this one out